# How can I generalize this bash command to work in a function?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash function that removes all files of a certain type recursively from the current working directory.  I have the function written that works when I type it in to the terminal:

```
find /tmp -name '*.swp' -exec rm {} \;
```

However, when I try to generalize the function by putting it in a function like this:

```
cleanup()
{
  find . -name *."$1" - exec rm {} \;
}
```

The actual output ends up being:

```
find . -name '*.swp' - exec rm '{}' ';'
```

and I get the error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: -
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `- exec` != `-exec`.  Extra spaces are bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your commands are the same

**cmd**: `find /tmp -name '*.swp' -exec rm {} \;`

**func**: `find . -name *."$1" - exec rm {} \;`

notice the space on `- exec` on your function. It should be `-exec`

**UPDATE**

On @Cyrus point, make sure the `*.` is placed inside the quotes to prevent bash globbing `find . -name "*.$1" -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: But note the point Cyrus made; that `*` should be inside quotes of some sort.  The script could be improved by using `+` in place of `\;` (it will delete multiple files in a single operation), or — if you have GNU `find`, use `-delete` in place of the `-exec` and subsequent options.

Comment: True, I was answering the question about the error OP was having. I'll update the answer with that comment.

Answer (score 4):

Quote `*` to prevent bash's globbing:

```
cleanup()
{
  find . -name "*.$1" -exec rm {} \;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out the space in your command is causing you issues.  Also, if your version of find supports it I think the -delete flag is a little easier.

```
cleanup()
{
  find . -name "*.$1" -delete;
}
```